# Why does Entity Framework not track changes when using repository pattern?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using repository pattern, and my update method looks like this:

```
    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = dataContext.GetEntry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entity);
        }

        string d1 = dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<string>("Description");
        string d2 = dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<string>("Description");

        bool b = d1 == d2;

        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

I am first getting the entity, then do the changes on the properties, and then update the entity. The entry's state is never `Detached` in this situation, so `Attach()` is never called.

If I change the `Description` property, I can see the original and current values are different. If the property remains the same, both original and current values are the same.

`GetEntry`is just a wrapper method in my DBContext:

```
public DbEntityEntry GetEntry(object entity)
{
    return base.Entry(entity);
}
```

My controller action looks like this:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Update(int id, CustomerTypeDTO customerTypeDto)
    {
        var entity = customerTypeService.Get(id);

        entity.Number = customerTypeDto.Number;
        entity.Description = customerTypeDto.Description;

        entity = customerTypeService.Save(entity);

        return Ok<CustomerTypeDTO >(Mapper.Map<CustomerTypeDTO >(entity));
    }
```

However, EF sends a SQL statement with all the entity's fields for updating, irrelevant if they were changed or not.

Why is EF behaving like this?

Comment: The pattern being used has nothing to do with it. It depends on how you load and update the entity. Do you disconnect and recreate it, for example using an HTTP POST to update?

Comment: Because that's how it works... It tracks changes to see if an entity has changed and then updates the entity as a whole if so.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes I use HTTP Post. I edit my question to reflect this. But as you can see, I'm loading the entity before doing the changes.

Comment: The answer to _"Why does `dataContext.GetEntry()` return an `DbEntityEntry` whose `State` isn't `EntityState.Detached`"_ is _"That depends on the implementation of `dataContext.GetEntry()`"_, don't you think?

Comment: @CodeCaster GetEntry() is just a wrapper method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this line:

`dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;`

You are telling entity framework that the entity has been modified. Irrespective of whether it actually has been modified.

Therefore EF sends a SQL statement with all the entity's fields for updating.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is this :

```
    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(entity);
        DbSetFactory.ChangeEntityState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
    }
```